# Javascript, Typescript, Angular 5 - Open and read file

Tags: javascript, angular, file, typescript

I am working with Angular 5, I have an application in which I need to read an AMP HTML file as text. This file is contained in a component and should only be accessed from this component.

I would like to be able to open the file in read-only by giving its name.

I'm actually searching for something like this:

```
let file = open('amp.html');
```

Is it possible? If not how can I do to achieve this?

Comment: In what environment? From a browser? NodeJS? Windows Metro app? Something else?

Comment: From the browser, you can't access the file system with JS due to the security issues it creates. If you are using Node, you can use the built in `fs` module to read and write from a file.

Comment: I developing with Angular, I have in a component a file that I would like to read

Answer (score 1):

## If you're writing browserside JS

You can't just simply read a file. The JS is running on your browser, and you need to think about where you're getting that file from.

If the file is on a server, you need to [fetch](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) that file from the server first by making a request for it.

If you're reading a file on the user's computer, you're gonna be using the [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) on the browser to allow the user to select that file.

## If you're writing backend JS

Assuming you're using NodeJS, you can conduct file operations like you would with other programming languages. Check out the `fs` module

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correct, you can read it as text like this:

```
function readFile(file){
    var raw = new XMLHttpRequest(); // create a request
    raw.open("GET", file, false); // open file
    raw.onreadystatechange = function (){ // file is ready to read
        if(raw.readyState === 4){
            if(raw.status === 200 || raw.status == 0){
                var allText = raw.responseText;
                alert(allText); // can be also console.logged, of course.
            }
        }
    }
    raw.send(null); // return control
}
```

usage:

```
readFile('link.html')
```

I solved this issue thankfully to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/how-to-read-a-local-text-file).

Comment: I have this message when using XMLHttpRequest:

[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.

Comment: This solution works for me on v5, I can give you a link to the project sample. 
Otherwise please provide more info, like module and component files.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/js39skue1sz1ovq/AAAbBGStl6gn9nLfkHD_oAVna?dl=0